# Routing to a directory outside of Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm sorry if this is a very vague question, however I have found no other solutions on stackoverflow or the Laravel 4 docs.

I have the following directory structure

`main / laravel`

`forums / forum installation`

`localhost` points to `main / laravel / public`

I want to access the contents of `/forums` in my browser like `localhost/forums` however since a `/forums` does not exist in `main / laravel / public` it returns 404.

Now, I simply can just move the contents of `/forums` into laravel's public directory however I want to try to get laravel separate from other non-laravel directories like forum softwares and wiki softwares.

---

So to recap, `localhost` returns 404 when accessing `/forums` because `localhost` points to `main / laravel / public` and `/forums` is located outside of the laravel installation. I would like to have `localhost/forums` access the contents of `~forums` and not search in `~main / laravel / public`. If it's more logical putting `~forums` in laravel's public folder, then please do explain to me because I've only been using laravel for around two months on one project.

Comment: Not really clear on what you mean here.. what do you have in the `formus` directory?  Are they "fully formed" HTML pages and therefore not to be handled as `route`s of your site?

Comment: In `~forums`, I have a forum software installation. It has nothing to do with laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [Alias in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) to route a specific URL to a specific directory on the filesystem.  For example:

server-wide (will apply to all VirtualHosts served by Apache)

```
Alias /forums /path/to/forums/install
```

or, for a specific VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/laravel/install
    ServerName your.domain.com
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    Alias /forums /path/to/forums/install
</VirtualHost>
```

Then anything incoming to localhost/forums will be served from that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server's public directory has nothing to do with Laravel, it's not Laravel's public directory!

So IMO there is no problem to put other application's files in the public directory.

You can also create a separate directory for Laravel's public stuff and put that in your main public directory in order to keep things cleaner. You can simply change Laravel's public directory in `bootstrap/paths.php` file.

For example from

`'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',`

to

`'public' => __DIR__.'/../public/laravel',`